# How to monitor file changes on a Linux device using inotify and cpp?

Tags: linux, c++, embedded-linux, inotify

I have cpp application running on an embedded-linux device. Now, I want the application to report if there is a change in a file on the device. I came across `std::filesystem` library and `inotify`(recommended) but couldn't fully understand how to integrate this into my application. Is there any wrapper or library for `inotify`? What dependencies should be met for `inotify` to work (lib)? Any example on getting started will be helpful. Can anyone please help me understand it?

P.S: Linux distribution is built using Yocto Project. Should I install any libraries(inotify-tools) using Yocto?

Comment: I don't know Yocto, in Ubuntu you'd install `libinotifytools0-dev` ... if integrating C into C++ seems to cumbersome this may help: https://github.com/erikzenker/inotify-cpp